# How to access a variable from another C# script in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on a simple game project, and have a problem. The problem is accessing the variable from one script to another.

For example :-

I have 2 Scenes (Game Scene and Game Over Scene), Game Scene has a Player Game Object , who has a int Variable Score.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Game_Scene_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{
     private int Score ;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () 
     {
          Score = 0 ;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () 
     {
          // Let us assume some one played the game
          // And Now the Score is 207
          Score = 207 ; 
     }
}
```

Now I want to access that int Variable Score in Game Over Scene which a Game Object.

So how can I access that int Variable from that script?

I searched for, but couldn't find any proper answer I wanted. Even-though some answers are in JavaScript , some are in Unity 4.x etc.

Comment: A Unity 4.x answer still works fine. This part of the fundamentals hasn't changed since Unity was first released.

Answer (score 2):

## You can't, it's private.

Now, that's not the end of things, as I suspect that wasn't really your question.

Firstly, you need a reference to this script.  Which you can get from a reference to the game object this script is attached to.  `GameObject.Find()` works sometimes, I don't recommend it, but none the less, once you have the GameObject reference...

```
Game_Scene_Script sceneScript = gameObj.GetComponent<Game_Scene_Script>();
int score = sceneScript.GetScore();
```

Of course, that still means you need to either make the Score public *or* provide an accessor function, `GetScore()`.

```
public int GetScore() {
    return Score;
}
```

Comment: You might want to include a quick implementation of `GetScore()`.  If the `public`/`private` paradigm isn't obvious to OP, exposing a `private` variable with a `public` function might not be either.

Comment: @GuntherFox Good point!  I didn't even think about that.

Comment: Or forget about Java getters and write a C# property instead: `public int Score { get { return  _score; } }` and access it more comfortably `int score = sceneScript.Score;`

Comment: *How* you write a getter isn't as important as *providing access*. ;)